# Add headers to CSV file via PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, csv

I have the following PHP script for creating CSV and collecting data from HTML form to CSV file, but I can't add headers to the first row of CSV file. I'm a newbie in PHP world so I'll appreciate if anyone can use this code to help me with that:

```
<?php

$fieldA = $_POST["prezime"];
$fieldB = $_POST["ime"];
$fieldC = $_POST["datumrodjenja"];
$fieldD = $_POST["mestorodjenja"];
$fieldE = $_POST["rod"];
$fieldF = $_POST["prebivaliste"];
$fieldG = $_POST["brojpasosa"];
$fieldH = $_POST["izdatod"];
$fieldI = $_POST["vazido"];
$fieldJ = $_POST["profesija"];
$fieldK = $_POST["zanimanje"];
$fieldL = $_POST["fiksni"];
$fieldM = $_POST["mobilni"];
$fieldN = $_POST["email"];
$fieldO = $_POST["napomena"];

$keys = array($fieldA,$fieldB,$fieldC,$fieldD,$fieldE,$fieldF,$fieldG,$fieldH,$fieldI,$fieldJ,$fieldK,$fieldL,$fieldM,$fieldN,$fieldO); //THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE FORM ELEMENTS ex: array('$fieldA','$fieldB',etc)

$fname = 'prijave.csv';
$fp = fopen($fname,'a');
//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));

fputcsv($fp, $keys);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a array with your keys, and create a loop to get values. Then use `fputcsv()` to write header and values:

```
$keys = ["prezime", "ime", "datumrodjenja", "mestorodjenja", "rod", "prebivaliste",
         "brojpasosa", "izdatod", "vazido", "profesija", "zanimanje", "fiksni", "mobilni",
         "email", "napomena"];

$values = [];
foreach ($keys as $key)
    $values[] = $_POST[$key];

$fname = 'prijave.csv';
$fp = fopen($fname,'a');
//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
fputcsv($fp, $keys);
fputcsv($fp, $values);
fclose($fp);
```

---

**Edit:** To add values but not BOM and headers each time, you could check if the [file exists](https://php.net/file_exists), and add them only if the file is new:

```
// same code as above ($header + $values)
// then,
$fname = 'prijave.csv';
if (!file_exists($fname)) {
    $fp = fopen($fname,'a');
    //add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
    fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
    fputcsv($fp, $keys);
}
else {
    $fp = fopen($fname,'a');
}
fputcsv($fp, $values);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do with the code you provided, but the problem is that always when I submit the form, it applies header and data, so the CSV file looks like 1st row = headers, 2nd row = data, 3rd row = headers, 4th row = data, etc. I need headers just on the first row, not on every second.

Comment: @kuzmvnovic Ok, so you should add a condition to add the header _and_ the BOM marker only for when your file doesn't exists. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Just one more thing, is it possible to change header names to something else, not to be the same as field names? When I change headers to something else, I get an error message.

Comment: @kuzmvnovic Yes, you can create another array with your labels, and use it in the first `fputcsv()`. See an example https://3v4l.org/fupcB (not working, of course, because there is not POST value, but show you a way to do this).

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php to find out about how fputcsv actually works.

Each call of the function writes one line of CSV from an array to the specified file.

The very first example illustrates that very well:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Therefore, beefore writing your forst line of data you should use fputcsv to write your headers. In your case that would look like that:

```
$headers = array("prezime","ime","datumrodjenja","mestorodjenja","rod","prebivaliste","brojpasosa","izdatod","vazido","profesija","zanimanje","fiksni","mobilni","email","napomena");

$fname = 'prijave.csv';
$fp = fopen($fname,'a');
//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));

fputcsv($fp, $headers);
fputcsv($fp, $keys);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do with the code you provided, but the problem is that always when I submit the form, it applies header and data, so the CSV file looks like 1st row = headers, 2nd row = data, 3rd row = headers, 4th row = data, etc. I need headers just on the first row, not on every second.

Comment: so, then do not appy it every time